# Confusion regarding 1st and 2nd electron gain enthalpy

Tags: electrons, periodic-trends, periodic-table, ionization-energy, electron-affinity

$\ce{O}$  has the 1st electron gain enthalpy $\pu{-141 kJ mol-1}$. $-ve$ value implies that energy is released when electron is added to an isolated atom. This also means that if $\pu{141 kJ}$ energy is supplied to $\pu{1 mol}\ \ce{O-}$ it forms $\pu{1 mol}\ \ce{O}$.

The second electron gain enthalpy has value $\pu{+780 kJ mol-1}$. This implies that energy is to be supplied to form $\ce{O^2-}$.  But if we supply $\pu{780 kJ}$ energy to $\ce{O-}$, would not the 1st added electron be removed; since it takes $\pu{141 kJ}$ of energy to be removed?

What am I missing?

Edit $1$- You guys are very rude. Seriously, $3$ downvotes but $0$ comments for a relatively well written question? Get over your attitude people.

Comment: @Poutnik Are Ionization enthalpy and Electron Gain Enthalpy not different?

Comment: @Poutnik Yes, I know they are different! My question was about electron affinities, but your comment referenced ionization energies.

Comment: @Poutnik Very sorry for the misunderstanding. Please see the edit.

Comment: Useful links for text and formula formatting:
 [Notation basics](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/notation)  /  [Formatting of math/chem expressions](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86/how-can-i-format-math-chemistry-expressions-here)  /  
[upright vs italic](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/443/which-symbols-are-written-in-roman-upright-font-and-which-are-italicized) // Use plain texts in CH SE titles. // For more, see [Math SE MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: E.g. write `$\ce{H2SO4}$` or `$\ce{a A <=> p P}$` or `$\pu{6.022E23 mol-1}$`  to get $\ce{H2SO4}$ or $\ce{a A <=> p P}$ or $\pu{6.022E23 mol-1}$ (all eventually with double dollars in the display mode like $$\ce{H2SO4}$$.

Comment: If downvotes are not commented, one can imply the default downvote reasons that appear at the downvote triangle mouseover. I have not downvoted, but element symbols in italics is a typographic sin. // Complains should be rather in  comments than in question.

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer is that the oxide dianion is [thermodynamically unstable in vacuo](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://uspex-team.org/static/file/PRB-2003.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwjs6OPL9M74AhWDhVYBHXD1CYQQFnoECCIQAQ&usg=AOvVaw0zyrfBoy-n3RGRTizV_hWJ)
(Warning: PDF autodownload) with +780kJ/mol of excess energy, i.e. it does take +780kJ/mol of energy to add an electron to an "oxygen monoanion", AND that the oxide ions we see in, say, magnesium oxide crystals, are sufficiently lowered in energy, by the magnesium cation's positive charges' attracting the oxides' electrons, that they do not have any excess energy and are therefore thermodymically stable.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I understand that $O^{2-}$ is unstable, but how **can** it be formed, since addition of the second electron requires an energy more than that required to remove the 1st added electron?

Comment: Let one say that the neutral oxygen atom has energy 0kJ/mol. The oxygen monoanion has energy -141kJ/mol and the oxygen dianion has energy (-141)+(+780)kJ/mol. NOT (-141)-(+780) kJ/mol.

Comment: To say it in different words; you are trying to subtract the "+780" your currenrmost result -141, when in fact you have to add it.

Comment: But is it not true that if we add the first electron affinity to the $O^-$  it becomes $O$?

Comment: O-: -141kJ/mol and O: 0kJ/mol

Comment: (-141) + 141 = 0

Comment: cf. O2-: 639kJ/mol and O-: -141kJ/mol

Comment: (639) + (-780) = -141

Comment: Sorry, but can you please elaborate?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137384/discussion-between-eisenstein-and-kanghun-kim).